# Why php doesnt find index send by JSON

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, json

Why doesn't PHP find my index, `myPostData`?

**jQuery/AJAX**

```
$('a').on("click", function(){
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "../image_view.php",
        data: {myPostData : {"lastName":"Sperrow", "firstName":"Jack"}}
        dataType: "json"
    })}
});
```

**PHP**

```
<?php
    var_dump($_POST['myPostData']);
?>
```

And I get the following error:

> ( ! ) Notice: Undefined index: myPostData in /var/www/image_view.php on line 7
>      Call Stack

```
#   Time    Memory  Function    Location
1   0.0001  228280  {main}( )   ../image_view.php:0

null
```

**var_dump($POST) when**

```
 data: {myPostData : JSON.stringify({"lastName":"Sperrow", "firstName":"Jack"})}
```

**output**

```
 array (size=0)
  empty
```

**var_dump($POST) when**

```
 data: {myPostData : "something"}
```

**output**

```
 array (size=0)
  empty
```

Comment: You want to do `var_dump($_POST);` to figure out what is going on.

Comment: What if you write `data : { myPostData : "some string" }` what does it do then? And use `var_dump($_POST);`

Comment: Can you explain more ? Give an example of correct code ? It's my first try to make something with json and ajax , so i dont know what does it mean application/json and how to resolve my problem.

Comment: Tryed , data : { myPostData : "some string" } - same error (no index). var_dump($_POST) error is array (size=0) empty

Answer (score 0):

The reason is because, for a content type of `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`, jQuery *typically* serialises the line below:

```
data: {myPostData : {"lastName":"Sperrow", "firstName":"Jack"}}
```

as

```
myPostData[lastName] => Sperrow
myPostData[firstName] => Jack
```

What would fix your problem is:

```
data: {myPostData : JSON.stringify({"lastName":"Sperrow", "firstName":"Jack"})}
```

Comment: I can't believe this also doesnt help. Maybe there is some issue becouse i use my javascript in twig template ?

Comment: What does var_dump($_POST) say for this and your original code? Update your question with the output in both cases.

Comment: array (size=0)
  empty - data: {myPostData : JSON.stringify({"lastName":"Sperrow", "firstName":"Jack"})}

Comment: array (size=0)
  empty -data: {myPostData : "something"}